# Rewrite Url Htaccess for profile user with "." (dot) htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to implement a rewrite rule for my users, this type:

```
  https://domain/user.strike18
```

The problem is that using this regex, any url containing "dot" returns error.

For example

```
 https://domain/register.php
 https://domain/styles.css
```

So I added a dot inside the regex rule.

```
  RewriteRule ^([@a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)$ user.php?p=profile&username=$1
  RewriteRule ^([@a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/$ user.php?p=profile&username=$1
```

Still not working, How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you face is that it is impossible for the rewriting module to decide whether something like "abcde.fghi" is a user name or a file name with a "file name extension".

You could try to work around that issue by explaining the exceptions to the rewriting module, here by means of a condition that allows the application of the actual rule to only get applid of the requested path does *not* point to an existing file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([@a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/?$ user.php?p=profile&username=$1
```

That however has the annoying implication that this now won't work as expected for a user called for example "styles.css" ...

The issue is actually rooted not in your rewriting attempts but in how you try to publish those user profiles. You should use a unique prefix for that to prevent such unsolvable problems. So a URL like  for example `https://example.com/profile/user.strike18`. That would obviously allow for a precise rewriting rule *without* any such naming collisions you currently face.